# Unable to execute update from flutter to API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I'm trying to update the API from flutter. So far i think flutter works fine in the flutter.dart it returns the value correctly, But im not sure if the API works correcly. Whenever i try to start the function in flutter the CMD returns this:

> Update Service Method Invoked
> [image: Cmd return]

And this is one thing he needs to return in the Controller.cs

IRepository.cs

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    Task<List<T>> GetData();
    Task<T> GetDataById(int id);
    Task<T> InsertData(T service);
    Task<T> UpdateData(T service);
    Task<bool> DeleteData(T service);

}
```

KlantRepository.cs

```
public class KlantRepository: IRepository<KlantModel>
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public async Task<KlantModel> UpdateData(KlantModel klant)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update method invoked");

        // _context.Entry(klant).State = EntityState.Modified;
        // await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        _context.Update(klant).Property(x => x.KlantId).IsModified = false;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        await UpdateData(klant);
        return klant;
    }
}
```

KlantController

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Klant")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class KlantController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IRepository<KlantModel> _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public KlantController(IRepository<KlantModel> repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<KlantModel>> UpdateService( int id, KlantModel klant)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update Service Method Invoked");
        try
        {
            if (id != klant.KlantId)
                return BadRequest("Employee ID mismatch");

            var employeeToUpdate = await _repo.GetDataById(id);

            if (employeeToUpdate == null)
                return NotFound($"Klant with Id = {id} not found");

            return await KlantRepository.UpdateData(klant);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                "Error updating data");
        }
    }
```

As you can see he does call the api but the api somehow doesn't continu if anyone can help me with this issue that would make my day!!! thanks already

____________ !! UPDATE !! ___________

This is my Postman request
[image: Postman request]

Comment: Can you show your KlantRepository.UpdateData(klant) method?

Comment: Why don't you just put a breakpoint and debug it?

Comment: that is the method in KlantRepository.cs: public async Task<KlantModel> UpdateData(KlantModel klant) @SafyanYaqoob

Comment: I have tried that otherwise i would ask for help @nvoigt

Comment: Well, what kept you from doing it? By the way, what is the reply you get? 400? 404? 500? All of them would not produce any more console output then what you got.

Comment: When using postman it gives me a  400 Bad request.  Sorry i should have mention this @nvoigt

Comment: Well, there you go. So `id != klant.KlantId` was true and your call failed. How does your call look like? Are you sure your model shouldn't for example come from the Body of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your POSTMAN request, you want this as a body, so make sure you tag it as such:

```
UpdateService([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] KlantModel klant)
```

Answer (score 1):

The server responds with a 400 Bad Request. That could mean that your payload is incorrect. You are sending a property called "Mailaddres"; shouldn't that be "Mailaddress" or "Mailadres"?
If it's correct check the other body properties with those from KlantModel.

[image: Possible typo?]

As a side note and maybe you already know that, but it's considered bad practice to directly send and receive model data. You should use DTOs and ViewModels instead. Cf. [https://medium.com/@enocklubowa/why-you-need-to-use-dtos-in-your-rest-api-d9d6d7be5450#:~:text=The%20DTO%20is%20helping%20you,manipulating%20data%20in%20the%20database](https://medium.com/@enocklubowa/why-you-need-to-use-dtos-in-your-rest-api-d9d6d7be5450#:%7E:text=The%20DTO%20is%20helping%20you,manipulating%20data%20in%20the%20database).

Comment: I have checked the body and the length thats all correct. In my code i also have DTO classes and models.

Comment: Normally not required for complex parameters, but try to add [FromBody] before the input parameter of "KlantModel klant" in method UpdateService( int id, KlantModel klant).